# problem with C program that prints out a linked list correctly from some but not all .dat data files of same structure

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Working on an assignment that reads in data from a choice of 3 .dat data files, saving each line of the space delimited file into
individual nodes of a linked list, then having the linked list sorted
and printed out by type. The type is given by a pointer to an array of
strings which is used to sort the linked list while it is traversing
over the linked list.

I've came to the conclusion that the data file is some how corrupted but highly doubt it. I was given 3 data files to work with and only the 2nd one is printing out correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

below are the input files
each one containing lines of data in order of ID,  # of units,  type,  and price

**ignore the commas that are separating the data for both the input and output, they are there just to clarify the form of the data per line...all data is space delimited for both input and output**

1st input file

321L    5   coat    16.99,
629X    14  pants   36.95,
619M    6   dress   41.99,
242M    23  shirt   9.95,
685X    6   coat    43.99,
270M    3   pants   82.95,
322X    8   pants   15.99,
289X    2   pants   85.95,
198M    11  dress   81.99,
319S    3   shirt   43.95,
433S    23  coat    125.95,
112L    10  blouse  24.99,
298M    6   dress   27.25,
543M    19  dress   35.46

---

2nd input file

321L    5   coat    16.99,
629X    14  pants   36.95,
619M    6   dress   41.99,
242M    23  shirt   9.95,
685X    6   coat    43.99,
270M    3   pants   82.95,
322X    8   pants   15.99,
289X    2   pants   85.95,
198M    11  dress   81.99,
319S    3   shirt   43.95,
433S    23  coat    125.95,
112L    10  blouse  24.99,
298M    6   dress   27.25,
543M    19  dress   35.46,
522X    6   pants   20.99,
689X    10  pants   90.95,
198L    9   dress   86.99,
349S    7   shirt   48.95,
439S    21  coat    130.95,
812L    8   blouse  29.99,
598M    4   dress   32.25,
549M    17  dress   40.46

---

3rd input file

198L    9   dress   86.99,
349S    7   shirt   48.95,
439S    21  coat    130.95,
812L    8   blouse  29.99,
598M    4   dress   32.25,
549M    17  dress   40.46

---

below are the actual outputs

1st output from file #1

0

Item type: pants

629X 14 $36.95,
270M 3 $82.95,
322X 8 $15.99,
289X 2 $85.95

---

2nd output from file #2

0

Item type: pants

629X 14 $36.95,
270M 3 $82.95,
322X 8 $15.99,
289X 2 $85.95,
522X 6 $20.99,
689X 10 $90.95

1

Item type: coat

321L 5 $16.99,
685X 6 $43.99,
433S 23 $125.95,
439S 21 $130.95

2

Item type: dress

619M 6 $41.99,
198M 11 $81.99,
298M 6 $27.25,
543M 19 $35.46,
198L 9 $86.99,
598M 4 $32.25,
49M 17 $40.46

3

Item type: shirt

242M 23 $9.95,
319S 3 $43.95,
349S 7 $48.95

4

Item type: blouse

112L 10 $24.99,
812L 8 $29.99

---

3rd output from file #3

0

Item type: pants

---

**intended output from all files is suppose to follow what the output is from file #2 which is sorting the data from file by type**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *types[5]={"pants", "coat", "dress","shirt", "blouse" };

    struct item
    {
        char id[5];
        int units;
        char type[7];
        float price;
        struct item *nextItem;
    };

    // Supply the remainder of the code to accomplish program
    // prompt and enter fileName - don't forget to test connection
    char *fileName = malloc(21*sizeof(char));

    printf("please enter the inventory file name\n");
    printf("\nyou wish to read data from");
    printf("\nplease enter file name--> ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    FILE *dataStream = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(dataStream == NULL)
    {
        printf("trouble opening file to read %s \n\n", fileName);
        printf("program has terminated");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n program can see file: %s", fileName);

    // Set up loop to read in each item to the list
    struct item *firstItem = NULL;
    struct item *lastItem = NULL;

    struct item *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
    newNode->nextItem = NULL;
    while(fscanf(dataStream,"%s",newNode->id)!=EOF)
    {
        fscanf(dataStream,"%d",&newNode->units);
        fscanf(dataStream,"%s",newNode->type);
        fscanf(dataStream,"%f",&newNode->price);

        if(firstItem == NULL)
        {
            firstItem = newNode;
            lastItem = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            lastItem->nextItem = newNode;
            lastItem = newNode;
        }
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
    }

    //  Set up loop to print out report.

    struct item *currentNode;


    printf("\n============================");
    printf("\nInventory Status");
    printf("\n============================");


    int index;
    for(index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    { 
        printf("\n\n\n%d", index);
        currentNode = firstItem;
        printf("\nItem type: %s", types[index]);

        while(currentNode != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(types[index],currentNode->type) == 0)
            {
                printf("\n%s %d $%.2f", currentNode->id, currentNode->units, currentNode->price);
            }

            currentNode = currentNode->nextItem;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: " Any help would be much appreciated." The best advice is to use a debugger to step through your code. If you really want someone here to help then please describe your problem clearer - what is the input data, expected output and actual output?

Comment: You are not setting `newNode->nextItem` inside the `while` loop. It means the last item always has an invalid `nextItem` pointer and using it causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Another bit of advice which will help you write code that is cleaner, more maintainable and more debuggable: Break up the code into smaller functions. For example, a function that adds an element to a list, a function that prints the list, etc.

Comment: If you want further help please respond to my second comment regarding `newNode->nextItem`. That needs to be fixed first and there is no point for any of us to help you further until you have tried that.

Comment: I think i did that already...its within the brackets of the else statement. i have been trying to add pictures for the input and output data but said I cant for some reason. sorry for not including it earlier...this is my first time using this site

Comment: I don't see any change to the code. Please post your updated code and tell us what effect that had. Also, don't post images. Copy the input and output as text and add it to the question.

Comment: Kaylum, are you saying that I didn't assign nextItem = newNode inside the while loop?

Comment: No, you never set `newNode->nextItem`. Inside the loop, immediately after the `malloc` you need `newNode->nextItem = NULL;`. Same as you did outside the loop.

Comment: it worked Kaylum, thank you! i'm relatively new to C and just recently started learning how to work with linked lists so i overlooked that